# Spring Integration do not response

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-integration

I use Spring Integration to handle my custom TCP protocol between server and clients. This is my context.xml:

```
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="serverConnectionFactory"
                               type="server"
                               host=""
                               port="5678"
                               so-linger="5000"
                               so-keep-alive="true"
                               single-use="false"
                               using-nio="true"
                               so-timeout="5000"
                               serializer="customeMessageSerializerDeserializer"
                               deserializer="customeMessageSerializerDeserializer"/>

<int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="inAdapter.server"
                                    channel="toSA"
                                    connection-factory="serverConnectionFactory"/>

<int:channel id="toSA" datatype="com.my.Message"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="toSA"
                       output-channel="toObAdapter"
                       ref="handleMessage"
                       method="handle"/>

<int:channel id="toObAdapter"/>

<int-ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter id="outAdapter.server"
                                     channel="toObAdapter"
                                     connection-factory="serverConnectionFactory"/>

<bean id="handleMessage" class="com.my.MessageHandler"/>
<bean id="customeMessageSerializerDeserializer"
      class="com.my.MessageSerializyerDeserializer"/>
```

When I deploy it via tomcat it works for serval minutes and it turn to be not responsive for client. One error found:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Unable to find outbound socket
at      org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpSendingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(  TcpSendingMessageHandler.java:122)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(  AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(  AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:154)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(  AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:102)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(  AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:105)
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpReceivingChannelAdapter.onMessage(TcpReceivingChannelAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection.sendToChannel(TcpNioConnection.java:370)
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection.run(TcpNioConnection.java:239)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I want to know how to fix it and where it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When using [collaborating channel adapters](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#_collaborating_outbound_and_inbound_channel_adapters), you must be sure to set the `ip_connectionId` header in the outbound message so the adapter knows which socket to write it to.

Generally, with a simple flow like that, the framework will take care of propagating the header from the inbound message to the outbound message.

So I need to see that method to see what you are doing.

What does your 'handleMessage` code look like?

The other possibility is the 5 second timeout - if your service takes longer than that the connection will no longer exist.

Generally, turning on DEBUG logging should help debug problems like this.